# Resque - Dequeue from named queue

Tags: ruby, resque

I have a job class that's sent to many different job queues, and that's easy:

   `Resque.enqueue_to queue, klass, *args`

but it's the flip side I can't figure out - there's no `dequeue_from`. Before I think about forking the gem to make one, does anyone know an existing workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`Resque.pop(:queue_name)` will dequeue one item from the front.

Comment: Yes, however, it skips all the callbacks that get triggered during a dequeue.